# Average of column skipping rows divisible by 5 using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to compute the average of the 1st column of a text file, skipping rows divisible by 5. As an example, consider the following set of data.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

For the data above, I can compute the average of the *entire* column using `awk` as

```
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }' file
```

which prints the result `5.5`.

How can I extend this code to exclude lines divisible by 5 from the average? For the example given above, this would exclude the numbers `5` and `10` from the average, resulting in a new average of `5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ NR%5? s+=$0 : c++ }END{ print s/(NR-c) }' file
```

The output:

```
5
```

---

- `NR%5? s+=$0 : c++` - ternary condition: sums all values `s+=$0` if record number `NR` is not divisible by `5`, else - count skipped records (to subtract them from average calculation)